# How can I do brace expansion on variables?

Tags: bash, shell, brace-expansion

Consider the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash -e

echo {foo,bar}
EX={foo,bar}
echo ${EX}
```

The output of this script is:

```
foo bar
{foo,bar}
```

I would like the the `echo` command to perform brace expansion on `${EX}`. Thus, I would like to see an output of

```
foo bar
foo bar
```

I want to create a script where the user can supply a path with curly brackets where every expanded version of it is copied.

Something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash -e

$SOURCES=$1
$TARGET=$2

cp -r ${SOURCES} ${TARGET}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is `cp -r foo bar foo bar` supposed to do?

Comment: Also you can't do brace expansion with variables, as it is evaluated before them.

Comment: don't make things over-complicated. You write your script once and then use it numerous times (probably). So, there is no reason to try to save on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `man bash`:

> The  order  of  expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.

As you see, variable expansion happens later than brace expansion.

Fortunately, you don't need it at all: let the user specify the braced paths, let the shell expand them. You can then just

```
mv "$@"
```

If you need to separate the arguments, use an array and parameter expansion:

```
sources=("${@:1:$#-1}")
target=${@: -1}
mv "${sources[@]}" "$target"
```

Comment: Good advice - if you accept already expanded arguments, then your shell script behaves more like other applications, and the user gets to use their shell in the normal way (rather than having to quote arguments that are to be globbed by the script).

Comment: Why `mv "$@"` brace expand works when it is in the script? What bash construct make this possible. And how it's different from question example? (which doesn't work).

Comment: @mauron85: because the shell expands the unquoted brace expression and your scripts gets a list of the arguments as parameters.

Answer (score 8):

This is a way:

```
ex=({foo,bar,baz})
echo ${ex[@]}
foo bar baz
```

Comment: Putting the values in an array is a scouche different that using *brace-expansion*

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This actually surprisingly works, you can put multiple braces inside and they expand as you would expect.

Comment: The nesting feature of braces is used thoughout bash. *Pattern-expansion with substring removal* is a great example.

Answer (score 1):

Brace expansion does not work the way you are attempting to use it. Brace expansion is basically used to generate lists to be applied within the context of the present command. You have two primary modes where brace expansion is used directly (and many more where brace expansion is used a part of another operator.) The two direct uses are to expand a list of items within a *comma-separated* pair of braces. e.g.

```
$ touch file_{a,b,c,d}.txt
```

After executing the command, *brace expansion* creates all four files with properly formatted file names in the present directory:

```
$ ls -1 file*.txt
file_a.txt
file_b.txt
file_c.txt
file_d.txt
```

You may also use *brace-expansion* in a similar manner to generate lists for loop iteration (or wherever a generated system/range of numbers in needed). The syntax for using *brace expansion* here is similar, but with `..` delimiters within the braces (instead of `','` separation). The syntax is `{begin..end..increment}` (where*increment* can be both positive and negative) e.g.

```
$ for i in {20..-20..-4}; do echo $i; done)
20
16
12
8
4
0
-4
-8
-12
-16
-20
```

(**note:** using variables for `begin`, `end` or `increment` is not allowed without some *horrible* `eval` trickery -- avoid it.).