# Bash : passing variable as a parameter for mkdir

Tags: bash, mkdir

I am trying to pass the variable $subdir which has the following string value :

```
subdir="subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}"
```

into the command mkdir in the following way :

```
mkdir -p $subdir
```

However, this is creating the following structure :

[image]

When I run this :

```
mkdir -p subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}
```

I get the structure that I want :

[image]

How do I make the command work while passing the path as a variable. I tried using quotes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of input/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Use `tree` command output instead

Comment: See ["How can I do brace expansion on variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270908/how-can-i-do-brace-expansion-on-variables) and the various linked Q&As.

Comment: Parameter expansions are not subject brace expansions. Define an array containing the results of the brace expansion, or define a function that performs the brace expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Brace expansion need to be *unquoted***, so:

```
mkdir -p subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}
```

Check https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

If you really need a variable:

```
eval mkdir -p "$path"
```

[image: warning]
Be sure that `"$path"` is not generated by `CGI` script, or by **any random user input**.

Comment: @pjh Depends on what `"$path"` produces. The result is only quoted long enough to pass the quote-less string to `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

The non-`eval` solution here is to use an array.

```
subdirs=( subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5} )
mkdir -p "${subdirs[@]}"
```

This is a case of [BashFAQ/050 - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) Syntax parsing, which handles things like Brace Expansion, comes before Parameter Expansion when bash evaluates the command line, so syntax characters inside of variables are going to be treated as literal data with no special meaning.

If you can't use this approach because the expansion isn't hardcoded for whatever reason, you can run a recursive function that doesn't rely on `eval` to do the work.

```
_f_mkdirs() {
  basename=$1
  levels=$2
  subdirs=$3

  # check the recursive exit condition
  if (( levels > 0 )) ; then
    # make however many directories at this level that you want
    for ((i=1 ; i <= subdirs ; i++)) ; do
      newdir="${basename}${i}"
      mkdir "${newdir}"
      # change into each directory and repeat the process until
      # you've descended to all levels
      # runs in a subshell to preserve current working state
      ( cd "${newdir}" && _f_mkdirs "${basename}" "$((levels-1))" "${subdirs}" )
    done
  fi
}
# to replicate your sample structure, call with: _f_mkdirs subdir 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ subdir=$(echo subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5}/subdir{1..5})
$ mkdir -p $subdir

$ var=$(echo subdir{1..2}/subdir{1..2}/subdir{1..2})
$ mkdir -p $var
$ tree
.
├── subdir1
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   ├── subdir1
│   │   └── subdir2
│   └── subdir2
│       ├── subdir1
│       └── subdir2
└── subdir2
    ├── subdir1
    │   ├── subdir1
    │   └── subdir2
    └── subdir2
        ├── subdir1
        └── subdir2

14 directories, 0 files
```